# Можно ли рассчитывать идентичные последовательности на основе srand?

Tags: c, случайные-числа, генерация-случайных-данных

Вопрос чисто философского характера:

Можно ли полагаться на базу рандомизации при генерации идентичных последовательностей на разных устройствах?

Например, задав некоторую базу(srand) и cгенерировав 100 чисел, можно ли быть уверенным в том, что именно эти самые числа будут сгенерированы с той же базой на более быстром/медленном по частоте процессора компьютере/телефоне etc..?

P.S В основе вопроса - функция srand из стандартной библиотеки C.
P.P.S В разных компиляторах получаются разные последовательности.

Comment: Да, для этого нужно что-бы реализации функций rand и srand были эквивалентны.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, нельзя. Реализация `srand` зависит от используемой стандартной библиотеки языка C - а она на разных компьютерах может отличаться. И даже на одном и том же компьютере она может отличаться. Даже если собирать одним и тем же компилятором.

Если вам требуется переносимый детерминированный генератор псевдослучайных чисел - его лучше написать самостоятельно.

Answer (score 2):

В случае одного и того же компилятора на разных машинах, например - да.

В случае разных компиляторов - нет.

Comment: Это связано с тем, что каждый разработчик компилятора предпочитает создавать собственную имплементацию srand?

Comment: `srand` скорее всего у всех одинакова, вот `rand` разная :) Но насколько я помню, этот момент - одинаковая последовательность - особо оговорен, в то время как реализация отдана разработчикам. Более того, в *C in a Nutshell* утверждается, что отсутствие вызова `srand` эквивалентно наличию вызова `srand(1)`. Для Visual C это точно так :)

Comment: Скорее не компилятора, а библиотеки языка Си, что всё-таки несколько иное. Стандарт языка говорит чётко: "If srand is then called with the
same seed value, the sequence of pseudo-random numbers shall be repeated." Плюс, я бы всё-таки не стал полагаться на идентичность вывода на разных машинах даже с одной версией библиотеки, библиотека может пытаться использовать разный код для разных платформ, хотя практическая вероятность подобного, наверное, невелика.

Comment: @RomanKhimov Согласен. Просто как-то не разделяю (может, и зря :)) компилятор и библиотеку.

Comment: @Harry: я привык к сочетаниям одного компилятора с разными библиотеками языка, поэтому сразу как-то так видится. Кстати, если вернуться к вопросу вывода на разных платформах для одной и той же библиотеки, то, если считать требование повторения как требование к библиотеке в целом, а не к конкретной сборке библиотеки, то всё-таки должны бы сходиться. Если быстро посмотреть на glibc/uClibc/musl/bionic, то у всех реализации без платформенно-зависимого кода, хотя у бионика есть некоторые дефайны, от которых реализация получится разная.